# Правильное построение where для маршрутов laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Есть следующий маршрут:

```
Route::get('catalog/{parentCat}/{childrenCat}/{productAlias}-{productId}.html',
      ['as' => 'productPage', 'uses' => 'ProductController@index']
)->where('productAlias', '([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z]+)-([-\w]+)');
```

Он работает на URL'ах, которые содержат минимум 2 знака тире (-). Почему так происходит? Т.е. на ссылке: `catalog/flowers/roses/101-rose-2.html` этот маршрут не работает, а на `http://larashop.loc/catalog/flowers/roses/101-rose-60sm-2.html` работает. Каким образом сделать, чтобы он работал и на первом варианте? Можно ли сделать в регулярке выражение `([-\w]+)` необязательным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
->where('productAlias', '[A-Za-z0-9-]+')
->where('productId', '[0-9]+');
```